# Unexpected token < trying to evaluate JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, vb6, webkit, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to add some html to a page in order to make jquery raise an event.

However, when I try to evaluate the JavaScript, my browser tells me

```
Unexpected token <
```

I have replaced all occurances of " with '. That didn't change anything.
I've also counted all "(", ")", "{", "}" and "<" and ">" to make sure I didn't miss any closing character.

But it all seems fine to me.

I'm not sure if there's actually a typo in my code or if I perhaps insert it at the wrong point of time (perhaps when the page is still loading)?

Is there anything wrong with my script?

```
<head>
      <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
      window.postComMessage("document ready occurred!");
});

$(window).load(function()
{
      window.postComMessage("window load occurred!");
});
</script>
```

ps: I'm trying to inject this code into [WebKit ActiveX](https://www.webkitx.com/) in order to get a notification when the browser has stopped loading. I insert this code when the page seemed to have stopped loading.

Comment: Your last `<script/>` should be `</script>`

Comment: @Akrion Thank you, I actually had this. I accidentally posted one of my attempts to make it work. I have changed the post accordingly.

Comment: You are missing an option in your function - it's expecting **2** arguments - not 1. However, this is for .postMessage - not postComMessage (couldn't find any docs with this function...) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Why the VB6 tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answer this for any other users of WebKitX:

The script is fine, but it's obviously not possible to inject qjuery this way.

I will update my answer as soon as I have know how to actually do it.

Edit: webkitx.com updated the browser so that the page loaded event only occurs after the page has been completely loading including all elements. 
Therefore I don't need my script anymore.

Answer (score 0):

How about that closing `<script />` tag... shouldn't that be `</script>` ?

Comment: Also regarding the webkit p.s. -> not sure if that "<>" is a valid operator.  I looked into c++, c#, vb and javascript... that may be part of your problem or a completely different problem...

Comment: That part of the code has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: okay - no worries - unfortunately, no answers either... a couple thoughts - make sure your browser cache is 100% cleared and try again?  you might also throw it into something like vscode configured with eslint.  Perhaps that will show you something.

Answer (score -2):

You need to escape the `<>`
After `If s` these characters will otherwise be interpreted as an HTML tag instead of JavaScript.

You could also put your JavaScript in a separate JavaScript file all together.

Comment: That is not part of the problem.

Comment: I have removed this code from my posting as it had nothing to do with the problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah okay no problem